# Multiplying in MIPS (00011 x 0110) in five bit MIPS processor

Tags: mips, smips

I would really appreciate somebodys help on this assignment by my proffesor. Thats all he send us and we need to send him a pdf document and i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: We don't know whta a 5-bit MIPS processor is or would be.  We don't know what form the answer would take.  You're showing a multiplication of 5-bit number by a 4-bit number, don't know what the significance of that is. But, fyi, 3 x 6 = 18.

Comment: Eric thats whats confusing me as well. Its the 5-bit MIPS processor sentance thats preventing me to finnish the assignment. I thought somebody here would know.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Probably best to ask your instructor for clarification.